# DM script/command for centerZLP under EFTEM mode

Tags: dm-script, hardware-interface

Is there any command that can do the thing similar as the centerZLP function in EFTEM mode??
Or perhaps, setting energy loss as zero also workable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From GMS 3.2 onward there should be a GIF tuning command that represents that functionality. It is not part of the officially documented script API though.

`Number GT_CenterZLP()`

Comment: This is it... Thanks a lot